# How to show string base on word in CSS from end to first

Tags: css

I have this string:

```
I am Saeid
```

I want convert the string like(end to first):

```
Saeid am I
```

How to show string base on word in CSS from end to first

Comment: Wrap "I am" and "Saeid" both in `span` elements, then try to use css `float`

Comment: I can not edit string and insert new span. My string like:
<div id="zl" style="">I am Saeid</div>

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need JavaScript then.

Comment: Ok. I will use JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.reversedTExt { direction:rtl; unicode-bidi:bidi-override; }
```

Apply this class to a paragraph tag and you should get the results your looking for.